# Can I use ItextSharp dll in sharepoint provider hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, pdf

I want to add a signature in each page of pdf so my question is can we use the third party DLL like itextSharp in provider hosted app in SharePoint?

Comment: You would be using that .dll in your .NET project not in SharePoint...

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of a provider-hosted App ([if any](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206685/sharepoint-development-past-and-future-how-to-keep-calm)...) is to off-load all the server-side code to a "third-party" server. This third-party server is anything you like (even PHP or Java if you like to rebuild all the oAuth token stuff in these languages). It is hosted anywhere you want (on your own premises, in the cloud, in Azure, ...). SharePoint/Office 365 {don't/cannot/doesn't want to} control what happens there.
You can do whatever you want with it (as per the policy of the hosting service you chose), including loading libraries, other DLL, etc.
So, in a word: *yes*, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you will add a third party dll to a .NET application you can add your reference to the AppWeb pf PHA.

You can add iTextSharp as a Nuget package as shown below :
[image]

After adding the nuget package, reference will be updated as :
[image]